# Ruby On Rails: Create stopped working but Update still works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I recently added an admin user to my page and now my 'create' function no longer works, but my 'edit' function still does.  I get no error when I try to create a new item.

**application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

before_filter :is_admin, only: [:new,  :create, :edit, :update, :delete, :destroy, :admin]

helper_method :admin?

protected

  def admin?
  session[:password] == 'pass'
  end


def authorize
  unless admin?
    flash[:error] = "unauthorized access"
    redirect_to root_path
    false
  end
 end

def is_admin
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You are not authorized for that." unless admin?
    end

end
```

If I take out the before_filter, it still doesn't work.

**members_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @member = Member.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @member }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @member = Member.new(params[:member])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @member.save
        format.html { redirect_to @member, notice: 'Member was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @member, status: :created, location: @member }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @member.update_attributes(params[:member])
        format.html { redirect_to @member, notice: 'Member was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my **routes.rb**  I have `resources :members`

Any ideas why my create suddenly quit on me but all the other functions are still working? It is like this for all of my pages, not just 'members'

Comment: what do you mean create does not work? What is in the log? Also - what is the code for is_admin, and does create work again if you comment out before_filter?

Comment: The code for is_admin is now above.  Commenting out the before filter doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your `is_admin` function? May be it return `false` or `nil` when you create member and `true` ect. when you update member.

P.S. Don't create methods with name like `is_admin` in Ruby. It is better to call it `admin?` ;)

Comment: I will add mu full application_controller.rb above

Answer (score 0):

Ah - try this in irb:

```
> "123" unless true
=> nil
```

See, when the user is an admin, it returns nil, which is interpreted as false, and the filter stops further execution.  You need it to do something like this:

```
def is_admin
  admin? || redirect_to(root_path, notice: "You are not authorized for that.")
end
```

Comment: Hmmm, that did not work either.  When I submit the form on a create, it does not redirect to the root path or tell me I'm not authorized.  It simply redirects to the members/index path without a notice of success or fail.

Comment: @fureelmusic,are you sure it rediects to the **members/index**? Because of your code it must redirect to `show`, `new`, `edit` actions or `root_path`.

Comment: So it seems like 'def create' is never actually being called.  I tried just doing a flash notification and it never pops up.  What could be the issue?

Comment: What does the console/log have it in regarding the request when you submit the form?  Is it showing that it is routing to index, or is it routing to create, but never reaching it?  Are you sure it is getting past 'is_admin'? What is your root_path?

Comment: `Started POST "/members" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-20 11:21:20 -0600
Processing by MembersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"dbHbwpZkja5Z6Kh+WXKdtwo6YIsLM


DFIh2t8wSkAgfg=", "member"=>{"name"=>"Thomas", "role"=>"Guitar"}, "commit"=>"Cre
ate Member"}
  ?[1m?[36mMember Load (0.0ms)?[0m  ?[1mSELECT "members".* FROM "members" ?[0m
  Rendered members/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 41.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

That's the console log for submitting a member.  My root_path is a home page in static_pages.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly certain that is_admin is working because I have a link to admin pages that are only shown if this condition is true, and that seems to be working fine.  I tried changing the before_filter to admin? rather than is_admin and there is no change

Comment: weird.  It is routing the post to '/members' to the index method.  That makes me think there is some oddity in your routes file, or possibly in your form declaration.

Comment: I think I may have figured out that the problem might have to do with using the id.  I think in the midst of trying to fix another issue I broke something with this and now it doesn't know how to reference something by an ID, or maybe isn't giving it one when it is created.

Would this have something to do with ActiveRecord or something of that nature?  I had tried using ActiveAdmin before but had no luck so when getting rid of that I think I broke something.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving all of my resources in my routes.rb file to the top of the file before everything else.  I'm not entirely sure why this was the problem, but everything is working now.

Comment: If you had a rule later on in your routes that matched, it would override the earlier resource declarations.  Glad you figured it out.  Another way to eyeball your routes is to use 'rake routes' and see what controllers and actions are being matched.